# NumPy : applying a function that takes a list as a argument to a list of list, and get a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I've got a problem and reading the doc doesn't help.
Okay, so basically, I've got some function that takes a NumPy list as argument, and returns a number. (Same as `np.average` for example). Let's call this function `f`.

Now, I have a list of lists `L`. So, `L[0]` is a list, `L[1]` is a list... 
And, I want to use NumPy parallelism to apply f to L and get as a result `[f(L[0]), f(L[1]),...]`.
Here comes my problem : when I call `f(L)`, the result's a number, this number being `f(flattened L)`.

I have no idea on how to fix that, could someone help me ?

Thanks,
Kal8578

Comment: Is `f` a numpy function, a custom function of your own or else?

Comment: It's a custom function of my own, that takes as argument a numpy list, calculates its average with np.average, and returns 1 if the distance between this average and a given constant is greater than another given constant.
The code being :
`def dist_moy_reel(L):
  return(np.abs(np.average(L)-x)>=d)`

Comment: numpy's speed comes from applying compiled numpy functions to numoy arrays.  Python level iteration, whether on arrays, or lists (of lists) is slower.

Answer (score 0):

What about transorming `f` into a recursive function?
Something like:

```py
def f(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [f(y) for y in x]
    # return what you previously wrote here
```

Comment: I think that this works, but the problem is that it's not using NumPy parallelism anymore.
What I mean is that for example, if I want to apply `cos` to a given list `L`, doing it with a `for` costs `O(len(L))` , whereas `np.cos(np.array(L))` costs `O(1)`. Thus, I wanted to use that property to avoid anything that's using a `for`/ a recursion / a `map` and would as a result cost `O(len(L))`or more.

Comment: `np.cos` isn't O(1),  It's just faster because the iteration is done in compiled code. Custom  `c` code that iterates on a simple `c` array would be just as fast.

Comment: Oh, so I was wrong about that. Thanks, it's for a Uni project, and tbh the lesson that we had highlighted in particular that np.something(np.somearray) is fast